# Getting Error CS0619:'HttpWebResponse.HttpWebResponse()' is obsolete: while using HttpWebResponse() default constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have upgraded my project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6. After upgrading, I am getting error as below while using `HttpWebResponse` default constructor:

```
throw new WebException("API is not matching. Appsettings API Url: " + _appSettings.CASRelationAPI + " ; remoteUrl to WebAPIMethod: " + url, new Exception(), WebExceptionStatus.TrustFailure, new HttpWebResponse());
```

> Error CS0619
> 'HttpWebResponse.HttpWebResponse()' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'

Please help me using `HttpWebResponse()` default constructor in .NET 6 or any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

from official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=net-6.0#remarks), remarks section:

> You should never directly create an instance of the HttpWebResponse class. Instead, use the instance returned by a call to [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse?view=net-6.0). You must call either the Stream.Close or the HttpWebResponse.Close method to close the response and release the connection for reuse. It is not necessary to call both Stream.Close and HttpWebResponse.Close, but doing so does not cause an error.